Understanding the Log-Sum-Exp (LSE) Operator in Chinchilla Replication Study, is e a set or exp?
I'm trying to understand the use of the Log-Sum-Exp (LSE) operator in the Chinchilla replication study, specifically the one referenced in the paper "Chinchilla Scaling: A replication attempt" by Besiroglu et al. (2024). In the study, LSE is used in the fitting process for a parametric model of loss. However, it seems that e is not used as the standard base of the natural logarithm but as a set of initial values for the parameter.
Why is e a set of values {-1, =0.5, ..., 1} and not the standard exponential function in the context of the LSE operator in the Chinchilla replication study?
Context:
The Chinchilla replication paper defines the parametric model and fitting process as follows:
$$
L(N,D) = E + A N^{-\alpha} + B D^{-\beta}
$$
In the Chinchilla replication study, the LSE function is used as follows:
$[
\min_{a,b,e,\alpha,\beta} \sum_{\text{Run } i} \text{Huber}_\delta \left( \text{LSE}(a \alpha \log N_i, b \beta \log D_i, e) - \log L_i \right)
]$
Here, LSE is not the traditional log-sum-exp but a function combining these logarithmic terms with the parameter

e initialized from the set {-1, -0.5, ..., 1}
Why the difference?
In this specific study, e is used as a parameter that is initialized from a set of values to optimize the fitting process. This is different from the traditional use of e in the log-sum-exp function, where e is the base of the natural logarithm. The choice of the set {-1, -.5, ..., 1}  for e allows the researchers to explore different initializations and find the optimal parameters for their model.
I hope this helps clarify the use of e in the Chinchilla replication study. If you have further questions or need additional details, please let me know!

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# Define the parametric model
def model_loss(N, D, E, A, alpha, B, beta):
    return E + (A / (N ** alpha)) + (B / (D ** beta))

# Define the Huber loss function
def huber_loss(delta, pred, actual):
    diff = np.abs(pred - actual)
    return np.where(diff < delta, 0.5 * diff ** 2, delta * (diff - 0.5 * delta))

# Example data (N: model size, D: number of training tokens, L: observed loss)
data = [
    {'N': 1e6, 'D': 1e9, 'L': 2.0},
    {'N': 1e7, 'D': 1e10, 'L': 1.5},
    # Add more data points as needed
]

# Convert data to numpy arrays
N = np.array([d['N'] for d in data])
D = np.array([d['D'] for d in data])
L = np.array([d['L'] for d in data])

# Define the objective function for optimization
def objective(params):
    E, A, alpha, B, beta = params
    L_pred = model_loss(N, D, E, A, alpha, B, beta)
    return np.sum(huber_loss(0.1, L_pred, L))

# Initial parameter grid
param_grid = {
    'E': [0, 0.5, 1],
    'A': [100, 200, 300],
    'alpha': [0.3, 0.5, 0.7],
    'B': [1000, 2000, 3000],
    'beta': [0.3, 0.5, 0.7],
    'e': [-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1]
}

# Perform grid search
best_params = None
best_loss = float('inf')
for E in param_grid['E']:
    for A in param_grid['A']:
        for alpha in param_grid['alpha']:
            for B in param_grid['B']:
                for beta in param_grid['beta']:
                    for e in param_grid['e']:
                        params = (E, A, alpha, B, beta)
                        loss = objective(params)
                        if loss < best_loss:
                            best_loss = loss
                            best_params = params

print("Best parameters:", best_params)
print("Best loss:", best_loss)

```


Did you ever find your answer?
